# Convert invalid string "1,5" to Single with "en-US" culture works

Tags: c#, converters

I'm trying to implement a numeric converter that takes an object and converts it to the required type.

I found a problem though: when I test "1,5" with the "en-US" culture Convert.ToSingle and Convert.Double simply returns "15" instead of throwing an exception that it cannot convert this value, which I would actually expect because "1,5" is invalid.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `"1,5"` is perfectly valid. Similar to how `"1,500"` parses to `1500`. Basically, the group separators (`,` in en-US) are simply ignored when parsing.

If you don't want it to do this, specify the `NumberStyles`:

```
int i = int.Parse("1,5", NumberStyles.Integer);
```

note that this is a `[Flags]` enum, and importantly I'm not including `AllowThousands`. Another approach could be:

```
int i = int.Parse("1,5", NumberStyles.Any & ~ NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

which allows everything *except* group separators. Of course, `"1,500"` will now fail.

Answer (score 1):

It would work if you specify e.g. russian culture - ru-RU, but using en-US you should use dot.

Comment: While true, this doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the comma is a valid group separator (it's used to indicate thousands).

So while "1,5" makes no sense to an English speaking human, the comma gets ignored by the parsing so the value is treated as "15".

Answer (score 1):

The comma is the thousand separator for en-US, so it is accepted.

Instead than `ToDouble()` or `ToSingle()` use [`Double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) or [`Single.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse.aspx), these function have an additional `style` parameter that allow finer control of which formats are accepted / rejected - see list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) - for example you can explicitly accept/reject the group separators.

Comment: if it works-but-does-the-unexpected-thing in `ToDouble` / `ToSingle`, then it will work-but-does-the-unexpected-thing in `Double.TryParse` / `Single.TryParse`.

Comment: No, because `Double.TryParse()` has additional options that `Convert.ToDouble()` does not have - I should have specified that. I expanded my answer